# How to add new column with value into DataFrameRow in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm working on some basic Genie app and would like to insert into first row of a dataframe 'data' new column with value but I haven't found a solution how to do it for a DataFrameRow. Please suggest the best approach

```
data = DataFrame(
    column = [1,2,3,4],
    value = [10,20,30,40]
)

data_row = data[1,:]
new_number = 100

insertcols!(data_row, 3, :new_column => new_number)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a new column to `DataFrameRow`. We can consider adding this functionality in the future.

However, what you can do is:

```
data_row = data[1:1,:]
data_row.new_column = [new_value] # note that new_value must be wrapped in the vector
```

or

```
insertcols!(data_row, 3, :new_column => [new_value])
```

(the difference is that you would work with `SubDataFrame`)

Comment: Thank you Bogumił for your answer and solution, that explains a lot!

Comment: I will soon open a PR for what you requested. You can track it in https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/3390.